# asp web application not updating after deployment

Tags: asp.net, deployment

To deploy my web application project I use one-click publish and web deploy. I assume all goes through fine since in vs output window after few seconds of waiting I see:

```
Updating setAcl (Myapp App).
Updating setAcl (Myapp App).
Updating filePath (Myapp App\Login.ascx).
Updating setAcl (Myapp App).
Updating setAcl (Myapp App).
Publish is successfully deployed.
========== Build: 2 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========***
```

In this case I have only made a label change on the Login form  and as you can see from above al went through fine. When I check the contents folder of the web application on the server the file is updated. But if I open the page in the browser the update is not there. I have cleared the browser cache, restarted IIS,, restart the application pool where this app runs but still no update sowing in the browser.  I checked the code it loads in the browser by using F12 and it still loads the file before update.

What I am missing here?

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have multiple publish destinations?

Comment: No, only one destination

Comment: With Web Application, I wonder if you need to update the dll. Can you try adding some text and then just do some modification to web.config. See if you see any change.

Comment: After publishing all the files in the application are updated, including dll files.

Answer (score 0):

Once I have removed  App_LocalResources folder with all the resx files the ascx files update fine.